# SSL handshake failure during socket connection. (Google/Android TV Remote Controller For iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, socket.io, sslhandshakeexception

I am creating an iOS demo where I am implementing the functionality to control a Google/Android tv using the iOS app by referring to the following link.

https://github.com/Aymkdn/assistant-freebox-cloud/wiki/Google-TV-(aka-Android-TV)-Remote-Control-(v2)

Also the working demo for this in Node.
https://github.com/louis49/androidtv-remote

I am implementing this using the socket IO library for iOS swift.

During the connection, I am facing the **SSL handshake failure**.

Here is the code

```
import UIKit
import SocketIO

class ConnectViewController: UIViewController {
    let manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: "wss://172.16.16.23:6467")!)
    var socket:SocketIOClient!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    
        let ssl = SSLSecurity.init(usePublicKeys: true)
        manager.setConfigs([.secure(true),.selfSigned(false),.security(ssl),.log(true),.sessionDelegate(self),.reconnects(false),.forceWebsockets(true),.forcePolling(true)])
        
        self.socket = manager.defaultSocket
        
        
        self.socket.on(clientEvent: .connect) {data, ack in
            print("socket connected")
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: So what is this? Swift or Objc? And please add what you have tried so far. A [mre] would be of help.

Comment: Have you tried using `.selfSigned(true)`?

Comment: @burnsi yes, it is not working.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a **TLS** connection instead of **WSS** to start the pairing process between an Android TV and your app. However, some TV vendors do not implement this capability because they don't have any certificates. I faced this problem with at least one TV vendor (coocaa).
To check if the certificate exists, you can try establishing a connection using OpenSSL

```
openssl s_client -connect <AndroidTV IP>:6467 -prexit -state -debug
```